# how to run a onetime method inside ngAfterViewChecked life cycle hook in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, lifecycle

I have a change of variable which needs to be tracked and I want to run some function after there's been such a change. So, I am using ngAfterViewChecked  hook to run the function. However, this method is a data submission. So, it need to run only once So, I used a status boolean variable to handle this as follows.

```ts
    ngAfterViewChecked() 
    {
        //status is a boolean variable which is true
        if (this.status)
        {
           this.status=!this.status;
           this.myFunction();
        }
    }
    myFunction
    {
        //some code
    }
```

But, I am detecting multiple data submissions in this approach(Verified after checking the database) and I am also getting following error.

**ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for '@dialogContainer': 'enter'. Current value: 'exit'.**

As far as I know ngAfterViewChecked is triggered for every change.So my guess is that, prior to changing the status to false, another instance has executed **if (this.status){}** before it was changed to false.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: ngAfterViewChecked is a bad hook for solvig a problem in 999 of 1000 cases. What is the scenario `this.status` is got updated?

Comment: @Andrei Are you suggesting me to listen to this.status value change? I didn't get your comment

Comment: I didn't suggest anything yet. to provide a better option for you I need to know the scenario, how `this.status` is being changed

Comment: @Andrei I was doing it inside the if clause to make sure it won't run again. if (this.status)
        {
           this.status=!this.status;
           this.myFunction();
        }

Comment: @Andrei Is there anything wrong with my proposed answer?

Comment: I would say your answer solves a little missarchitecture that appeared before. Better way is to call your logic when the event (that in your case updates "this.status") is emmited. tracking the variables in the way you are trying is considered a bad practice. That is one of the reason AngularJS is dead and instead Angular2+ is created

Comment: @Andrei So I should call myFunction() when this.status is emiited as follows. ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.counter == 0) {
      this.counter++;
      if (this.counter == 1) {
        this.paymentListener.next(this.counter);
  this.myFunction();
      }
    }
  } Is this coorect?

Comment: as I've already said, the correct way is not to use `ngAfterViewChecked` hook. it is called too often. There is not enough context to help you with exact option you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few hours searching, I was able to overcome it.This is how I did it.I will start with a bit of explanation to my solution.

- Angular works in a browser. Browsers run JavaScript.Javascript code is executed in a single thread but Javascript runtime is not run in single thread. We don’t have to worry about it as Runtime takes care of it.
- Subject is an observable. It can be used to emit a value to any number of observers which are listening to it
- Subscription can hold a observable

First I created a Subject called paymentListener,integer variable called counter and a Subscription called oneTimePayment.

```
oneTimePayment: Subscription;
  private paymentListener = new Subject<number>();
  counter = 0;
```

Then inside the onInit method,I made the subscription.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    
    this.oneTimePayment = this.paymentListener.subscribe((counter) => {
          if (counter == 1) {
            //this is my function
            this.myFunction();
          }
        });
    
    }
```

Then inside the ngAfterViewChecked life cycle hook I used the paymentListener (this is a Subject) to emit the counter value.

```
 ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.counter == 0) {
      this.counter++;
      if (this.counter == 1) {
        this.paymentListener.next(this.counter);
      }
    }
  }
```

Since, the value is emitted by the paymentListener (Subject) only if the counter is equal to 1. So, on the subscription made inside the onInt will get the emitted value and there I only execute the myFunction() only if the emitted value is equals to 1;
This ensures the method is running only once after a change.

Finally,make sure to call the unsubscribe inside ngOnDestroy. If not it will result in memory leaks.

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
    this.oneTimePayment.unsubscribe();
  }
```